# No such table upon initial Django migration

Tags: django, sqlite, djongo

**Back story:**

I'm creating a quiz app. I started by wanting to use Django (v=2.1.4) with Mongo via the Django package. Everything worked until it didn't so I decided to just drop Django and mongo entirely and go back to SQLite. I only mention it in case it is related, but I don't think it is.

I made a copy of the project then deleted the original. I then created a new project with the same name and all the same apps. This created a bunch of new folders with blank files. I moved the copies of the original over to these folders (except the migration files) and replaced the blank files with the same name.

I changed the `mysite/settings.py` file back to default to read:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hoquidb'), 
  }
}
```

To my knowledge, this creates a fresh project ready for it's initial migration and it will use sqlite3.

**The problem:**

So I tried to do the initial migration and got a cryptic error message:

```
    (base) C:[redacted]\testabode\Hoqui\hoqui>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 296, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: realestate_sentence_beginning

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
        self.check()
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 60, in _run_checks
        issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
        return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
        return check_method()
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
        for pattern in self.url_patterns:
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
        patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
        res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
        return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:[redacted]\testabode\Hoqui\hoqui\hoqui\urls.py", line 24, in <module>
        path('quiz_taker/', include('quiz_taker.urls')),
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
        urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:[redacted]\testabode\Hoqui\hoqui\quiz_taker\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
        from . import views
      File "C:[redacted]\testabode\Hoqui\hoqui\quiz_taker\views.py", line 2, in <module>
        from quiz_maker.tests.generate_questions import main as question_list_func
      File "C:[redacted]\testabode\Hoqui\hoqui\quiz_maker\tests\generate_questions.py", line 22, in <module>
        sentence_beginning(text=first_words_of_sentence,category='Location').save()
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 718, in save
        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 748, in save_base
        updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 831, in _save_table
        result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 869, in _do_insert
        using=using, raw=raw)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1136, in _insert
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1289, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "C:[redacted]\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 296, in execute
        return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: realestate_sentence_beginning
```

Comment: Have you tried `find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete`
`find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete` ? Not sure, but this helps me a lot by deleting the migrations in my project. It's two separate commands.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you're importing the test file `quiz_maker.tests.generate_questions` into your views. That file has code at the top level which tries to save an element into the database. But since that code is executed at import time, the migration won't have had a chance to run yet, and the table is not created.

You should not be doing either of those things: don't import test files into your actual code, and even in test files don't perform db-modifying actions at module level, they should be done inside functions that are called when necessary.